# android okhttp3 post header miss httponly cookie item

Tags: android, cookies, okhttp

Implement cookiejar and print log

```
@Override
public List<Cookie> loadForRequest(HttpUrl url) {
    List<Cookie> cookies = persistentCookieStore.get(url);
    for (Cookie c : cookies)
        Log.d("zzzzzzzzz", c.toString());
    return cookies;
    //return persistentCookieStore.get(url);
}
```

open an website

> OkHttp  : <-- 200 OK https: //bbs.et8.net/bbs/forumdisplay.php?sort=dateline&order=desc&page=1&f=147 (317ms)
>
> OkHttp  : Server: nginx/1.8.1
>
> OkHttp  : Date: Thu, 14 Jul 2016 13:09:40 GMT
>
> OkHttp  : Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
>
> OkHttp  : Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>
> OkHttp  : Connection: keep-alive
>
> OkHttp  : Vary: Accept-Encoding
>
> OkHttp  : X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.41
>
> OkHttp  : Set-Cookie: bbsessionhash=ebaf33d3eed4e3371d6a6b7013d7530e; path=/; domain=.et8.net; HttpOnly
>
> OkHttp  : Set-Cookie: bblastvisit=1468400840; expires=Fri, 14-Jul-2017 13:09:40 GMT; path=/; domain=.et8.net; secure
>
> OkHttp  : Set-Cookie: bblastactivity=0; expires=Fri, 14-Jul-2017 13:09:40 GMT; path=/; domain=.et8.net; secure
>
> OkHttp  : Cache-Control: private
>
> OkHttp  : Pragma: private
>
> OkHttp  : X-UA-Compatible: IE=7
>
> OkHttp  : Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
>
> OkHttp  : X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
>
> OkHttp  : <-- END HTTP

post data to server:

> OkHttp  : --> POST https:// bbs.et8.net/bbs/login.php http/1.1
>
> OkHttp  : Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> OkHttp  : Content-Length: 167
>
> OkHttp  : --> END POST
>
> zzzzzzzzz: bblastactivity=0; expires=Fri, 14 Jul 2017 13:09:40 GMT; domain=et8.net; path=/; secure
>
> zzzzzzzzz: bblastvisit=1468400840; expires=Fri, 14 Jul 2017 13:09:40 GMT; domain=et8.net; path=/; secure
>
> zzzzzzzzz: bbsessionhash=ebaf33d3eed4e3371d6a6b7013d7530e; domain=et8.net; path=/; httponly
>
> OkHttp  : <-- 200 OK https://bbs.et8.net/bbs/login.php (76ms)
>
> OkHttp  : Server: nginx/1.8.1
>
> OkHttp  : Date: Thu, 14 Jul 2016 13:09:49 GMT
>
> OkHttp  : Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
>
> OkHttp  : Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>
> OkHttp  : Connection: keep-alive
>
> OkHttp  : Vary: Accept-Encoding
>
> OkHttp  : X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.41
>
> OkHttp  : Set-Cookie: bblastvisit=1468400840; expires=Fri, 14-Jul-2017 13:09:49 GMT; path=/; domain=.et8.net; secure
>
> OkHttp  : Set-Cookie: bblastactivity=0; expires=Fri, 14-Jul-2017 13:09:49 GMT; path=/; domain=.et8.net; secure
>
> OkHttp  : Cache-Control: private
>
> OkHttp  : Pragma: private
>
> OkHttp  : X-UA-Compatible: IE=7
>
> OkHttp  : Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
>
> OkHttp  : X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
>
> OkHttp  : <-- END HTTP

why the post header miss cookie item: set-cookie:bbsessionhash  ?

Comment: because `httponly`

Comment: But HTTPUrlConnection can handle httponly and auto add to headers when post data to sever.  How to let Okhttp3 auto add httponly  cookie to headers too